# MediaPlayer - Can't Find Voice Note File Path

Tags: android

I recorded a voice note on my Samsung Galaxy S6 and labeled it "Hello.m4a".
I have a MediaPlayer object called mp. I'd like for this object to play the voice note when the user presses a button. However, I can't seem to figure out what the file path for voice notes are?

My questions are

A) Is there a general file path that I can use to get into the folder containing all of the voice notes? 
B)If not, how could I find the path programmatically?

Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to do without any success:

```
mpintro = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/hello.m4a"));
mpintro.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have all the necessary permissions?
Check your manifest, it shoud include:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Check permission in your application (For example in onCreate() method):

```
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
```

Check your path to file from some file explorer.
For example path (Internal Storage)/Sounds/Hello.m4a you can get like this:

```
String voiceNotePath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + "/Sounds/Hello.m4a";  // voiceNotePath = "/sdcard/Sounds/Hello.m4a"
```

Using "EXTERNAL_STORAGE" is normal, because internal memory of modern phones is big enough and defined like "EXTERNAL".